# adding image at the top of the container

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Following is my code, I am trying to make something which look like [image: this] 
My code is given below:

```css
 .service-box {
        background: #fff;
        margin: 0 -5px 20px;    ;  
        font-size: 16px;
        text-align: center;
        text-decoration: none;
        padding: 50px 30px;
        -webkit-transition: background 0.5s;
        -o-transition: background 0.5s;
        transition: background 0.5s;
    
    }
    
    
    .service-box:hover {
      background: #84a499;
      color: #fff;
    }
    
    .service-box:hover .btn-primary {
      background: #fff;
      color: #222121 !important;
    }
    .service-box:hover .icon-rounded {
      background: #688d80;
    }
    
    .service-box .service-title {
      padding: 30px 0 22px 0;
      margin: 0;
      font-weight: 300;
    }
    
    .service-box .service-title a{
        color: #222121;
    }
    
    .service-box:hover .service-title a {
      color: #fff;
    }
    
    .service-box .btn{
        margin-top: 10px;
    }
    
    .service-box .btn .fa{
        margin-left: 5px;
    }
    
    .service-box .icon-rounded{
        width: 80px;
        height: 80px;
        border: 1px dashed #e1e1e1;
        display: inline-block;
        border-radius: 50%;
        text-align: center;
        line-height: 80px;
    }
    
    .service-box .icon-rounded:before{
        font-size: 50px;
        margin-left: 0;
    }
```

```html
      <!-- Web Fonts -->
      <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300,300italic,400italic,500,700,900,500italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
      
     <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous"/>
      <!-- Main CSS -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="services/css/style.css" />
       

 
   


        <div class="container-fluid" style="background-color: white;">
         <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12" style="margin-bottom: 100px; margin-top: 100px" >
          <h1>My First Bootstrap Page</h1>      
          <p>This part is inside a .container-fluid class.</p> 
          <p>The .container-fluid class provides a full width container, spanning the entire width of the viewport.</p>   
          </div>
          
        
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-16" style="margin-bottom: 100px; margin-top: 100px"  >
          <div class="service-box">
           <span class="icon-rounded flaticon-business70"></span>
        
            <h2 class="service-title"><a href="services-single.html">Information Design</a></h2>
        
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit sed rhoncus ex condimentum. Donec placerat nunc ut porttitor blandit. Duis ex nisi, tristique nec nullaf non.</p>
        
            <a class="btn btn-primary" href="services-single.html">Read More <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right"></i></a>
              </div>  
          </div>
          
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-16" style="margin-bottom: 100px; margin-top: 100px">
          <h1>My First Bootstrap Page</h1>      
          <p>This part is inside a .container-fluid class.</p> 
          <p>The .container-fluid class provides a full width container, spanning the entire width of the viewport.</p>   
          </div>
          
          </div>
        </div>
```

My output looks like [image: this]

I am trying to make my second image look like first one, I have copied all the required code,I dont know what to do from here, i am stuck since hours now. please let me know what should I do. I am trying to make is an image at the top and then title and description at the bottom and a read more option in separate rectangles.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use nested rows with bootstrap grid system to split col in n-parts as per your requirements

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-16 col-4" style="margin-bottom: 100px; margin-top: 100px">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <div id="image" class="text-center m-6">
          <img src="https://www.thefamouspeople.com/profiles/images/a-p-j-abdul-kalam-2.jpg" class="rounded-circle img-thumbnail" alt="image" width="200px" height="200px"/>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-12">
        <div class="service-box">
      <span class="icon-rounded flaticon-business70"></span>

      <h2 class="service-title"><a href="services-single.html">Information Design</a></h2>

      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit sed rhoncus ex condimentum. Donec placerat nunc ut porttitor blandit. Duis ex nisi, tristique nec nullaf non.</p>

      <a class="btn btn-primary" href="services-single.html">Read More <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right"></i></a>
    </div>
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>
```

Here is link of working demo only for one col https://codepen.io/IamMonikaPatel/pen/VdrQry

Comment: hey, Thank you, unfortunately, it isnt working with me. I dont know, why I copied everything as it is, is there something else I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

Inside the div for each box you should include a div for the circular image. This image should have CSS styling similar to the following:

```
.anyClassNameOfYourChoice {
display: block;
margin: 20px auto 20px;
height: 20px;
width: 20px;
border-radius: 50px;
}
```

You'll need to define what the image is, which can be done using CSS or HTML. If you want what's presented in the example, just use the following:

```
border: 1px dotted #cecece;
```

In terms of making only the second box look like the one in the example, you'll want to either directly apply a class exclusive to that box, or use nth child in CSS to only apply certain CSS to the second element of the parent container. Whatever you choose to do, you'll want to include the following styling:

```
background-color: #008080
```

Note that the above colors are just examples within the same spectrum of the example, but may not be 100% accurate.